# How do I add foreign keys into a new table in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, foreign-keys, primary-key

I want to add the primary key from 2 tables (project and book mark) into a new table called ProjectBookmark which contains the primary key from my other two tables as foreign keys with the relationships shown below in springbok.

ERD Diagram

[image: ERD Diagram]

Below are my tables for Project and bookmark

Table 1

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Project_Name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Description", unique = true)
    private String description;

    public Project(String name, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
```

Table 2

```
@Entity
public class Bookmark {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Type_of_resource", unique = true)
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "Description", unique = true)
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "URL", unique = true)
    private String url;

    public Bookmark(String name, String type, String description, String url) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
    }
```

Im not sure how to do the relationships and import in the primary keys as foreign keys to my table 3.

```
@Entity
public class ProjectBookmark {



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you need a `ManyToMany` relationship between `Project` and `Bookmark`.

You'll need to add the following code to your `Project` entity class.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="project_bookmark",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="bookmark_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
)
private Set<Bookmark> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();
```

You don't need an additional `id` column in your `ProjectBookmark` table.